# 100% of variance explained by one principal component

Tags: pca

I am new to PCA and trying to do some analysis on my data set. When I apply PCA to my set of data I get all 100% variance on only one principal component. Does this make any sense?

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Please describe your data: how many variables, what their ranges are, and how you are attempting to do PCA.  It's possible you're doing PCA on a covariance matrix and that one variable has a variance so much larger than all the others that it is dominating the calculation.  What does the scatterplot matrix of the variables look like?

Answer (score 6):

This means all your variables can be written as a linear transformation of a single one of them, which is a pretty extreme case of linear dependence.

(Why? Because all the principal components of a dataset together are always a basis for the vector space spanned by the original variables.)

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate on @Kodiologist's answer (+1): let's say your data matrix is $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$, and let $X = UDV^T$ be the SVD of $X$. Let's further assume that $X$ has been normalized so that $X^T X = V D^2 V^T$ is the covariance matrix. It is well known that the variance explained by the first $k$ principal components is $\sum_{i=1}^k d_i^2 / \sum_{i=1}^p d_i^2$ (feel free to ask for more details here). If $d_1^2 / \sum_{i=1}^p d_i^2 = 1$ then $d_2 = \dots = d_p = 0$ so this tells us that $X = d_1u_1 v_1^T$, i.e. $X$ is a rank 1 matrix, which is what it means to have all $p$ variables be perfectly collinear. We also have that the covariance matrix is $d_1^2 v_1 v_1^T$ which is also rank 1

Comment: Thank very much for your answer. So this means that I have a redundant set of data, so does PCA tell me which one of my variables it is, that all the other variables are  linearly dependent on it?

Comment: If your matrix is rank 1, then every column is a multiple of any other column. Unless your application tells you otherwise, there isn't really a canonical column that generated the others.

Comment: MATLAB example: Of such an extreme case: `rng(123); svd(repmat(randn(100,1),1,4).*repmat(1:4,100,1))` returns a single non-zero eigenvalue, ie. all the variance lies on a single PC.

Answer (score 2):

One feature with large numeric range might dominate the others.

Try to apply standardization on your dataset before PCA, by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance.